# Can't rename file in Shell script

Tags: linux, shell

Is there anything I'm doing wrong here in this piece of code?

```
OLD_NAME="$FILE"
NEW_FILE=`${OLD_NAME | tr ' ' '_'}`
/bin/mv "$OLD_NAME" "$NEW_FILE"
```

All I want is to rename the supplied file and replace all the spaces with underscores.
I'm getting `bad substitution` error message. I can't seem to get the renaming to work  :-(

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to echo the OLD_NAME into tr:

```
OLD_NAME="$FILE"
NEW_FILE="$( echo "$OLD_NAME" | tr ' ' '_' )"
/bin/mv "$OLD_NAME" "$NEW_FILE"
```

But perhaps you would prefer:

```
NEW_FILE=${OLD_NAME// /_}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It works but I now have another issue. It's failing when there's no spaces in the file name. Is there a way to handle both cases? The renaming is not working. Thanks for your support, William :-)

Comment: Try `test "$OLD_NAME" != "$NEW_NAME" && /bin/mv ...` so that you only attempt to move the file if the name has changed.

Comment: Thanks again Williams, you deserve and award. Your idea of using a test worked. I appreciate your support, God bless.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the substitution more simply/readably without the pipe and `tr` using this:

```
NEW_FILE=${OLD_NAME// /_}
```

See [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/bash-shell-parameter-substitution-2.html) for more details.

Comment: Note that `//` will replace all spaces, but `/` will only replace the first.